# Android error value at image org.json.jsonobject$1 cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: android, json

```
 JSONArray arrayUpcoming = response.getJSONArray("results"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayUpcoming.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentMovie = arrayUpcoming.getJSONObject(i);


                String iconImage = null;
                String background = null;

                //images
                if (currentMovie.has("image")) {
                    JSONObject objectImages = currentMovie.getJSONObject("image"); 
                    if (objectImages.has("icon_url")) {
                        iconImage = objectImages.getString("icon_url");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+ iconImage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (objectImages.has("screen_url")) {
                        background = objectImages.getString("screen_url");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+ background, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
}
```

This doesn't make sense, my code seems pretty normal to me. Sorry I can't give you more insight on the context 'cause I can't seem to wrap my head around the error, like what's ***jsonobject$1*** for starters

Comment: At-least post the error stack, at which line it is occurring. But from the header 'value at image org.json.jsonobject$1 cannot be converted to jsonobject' it seams that the Image in json doesn't represents the jsonobject.

Comment: Please add your logging. On which line do you receive the error? I would expect jsonobject$1 to have something to do with your call arrayUpcoming.getJSONObject(i) but that is just a wild guess.

Comment: Post your log to help you in better way.